# adding variables to curl_easy_setopt (seg fault)

Tags: c++, curl, segmentation-fault

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


int rad = rand() % 100000;
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + rad;
std::string full_agent_name = agent_name + std::to_string(rad);

int main(int argc, char **)
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, full_agent_name.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
```

I do not understand why this is seg faulting. I am new to C++ and only really know python3 any help would be super great, have a good day!

Comment: What is the point of adding `rad` to both `agent_name` and `full_agent_name`? Seems you shouldn't be adding `rad` to `agent_name` at all: `std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/"; std::string full_agent_name = agent_name + std::to_string(rad);`

Comment: ya lol I should of reviewed it better, typo :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + rad;
```

This does not do what you expect. This adds `rad` bytes to the address of the string literal. Try

```
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + std::to_string(rad);
```

or

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/"s + std::to_string(rad);
```

Unrelated to your question. `int rad = rand() % 100000;` will give the same random number rad each run if the pseudo random number generator is not seeded with srand.

Update. You have two variables agent_name and full_agent_name. It seems `+ rad` in the first variable assignment is a typo and should be removed.

Comment: Ya i know it will give the same number kind of need it, but none the less you are the best!